# Should we prefer tags with hyphens?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I've noticed that a lot of the newer StackOverflow users tend to make use of ambiguous tags. For instance, many of the posts about [Android fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) use the [fragment](/questions/tagged/fragment) tag instead of the more specific (and correct, in my opinion) [android-fragments](/questions/tagged/android-fragments) tag.

Should we edit posts that use ambiguous tags or is this considered not a big deal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. The [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag says this in its description. I assume this would carry over into other tags as well.

[image: "Please use the Android-specific tags such as [android-intent], not [intent].]