# New Post Notices are reverted to old ones

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, post-notices

As of today I not longer see new Post Notices across SE sites. They are all reverted to old ones.

[Question with old notice on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965033/multiple-linux-debian-ubuntu-2018-2019-centos-fedora-grub2-2-04-installation)

[Question with old notice on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/232702/is-it-safe-to-use-super-global-variable-post-in-pdo-query)

[Question with old notice on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338777/rules-around-deleting-or-editing-tags)

Same happened with Close Vote dialog.

I have only single account, so I cannot be accidentally logged in as different user.

Is this intentional rollback or a bug?

---

According to [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow) once you are in one group of users that either see or don't see new notices and you cannot change groups. Or at least that is how I read it.

> During our initial launch period the new post notices (and all related
>   changes) are being shown to 50% of users. There is no easy way to
>   switch between the group of users seeing old or new notices. If there
>   are things about the new notices that you dislike, please let us know
>   in a respectful and constructive way. We are happy to receive and take
>   all feedback into consideration.

Comment: No repro. Link please? (To a question you see with old notice)

Comment: Did they ever mention the A/B tests were completed? I saw the reversal today and assumed I was still being moved between groups. Or maybe they are getting ready to actually deploy this network wide, hence the regression.

Comment: @yivi I have no idea whether test are completed or not, but since it started I had new notices all along.

Comment: "Lucky" you. I've seen different notices all the time. Sometimes new, sometimes old.

Comment: Isn't the A/B Testing phase still ongoing, e.g 50% of users see new and 50% old ones?

Comment: I see a new-style notice on the SO question, and an old-style notice on Code Review and Meta.

Comment: I thought the new notices were only visible on SO. Haven't ever seen them on MSO, for example. Nor here.

Comment: @yivi I think I saw them here, too. But I maybe wrong as I wasn't paying that much attention on Meta posts

Comment: FYI, the A/B groups were not account locked. A user with the same could be moved around from one group to the other at different points in time. So "logging in as a different user" is not necessary to suddenly finding yourself as part of a different group.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are moved from A <-> B, this ***was*** mentioned in [this deleted comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow/337038#comment1119319_337013) and mentioned in this [not deleted comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow/337038#comment1121390_337038) to [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337038/282094):

[image: comment screenshot]

Official answer, in a comment to this question: "[New Post Notices (Closed/On Hold/etc.) rolling out on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390887/3648282)":

> "@NeilLunn the MSE post specifically made mention that 50% of users would see the new and 50% would see the old. It has been discussed a whole bunch in comments. **A/B grouping is based on IP address** - some (though still a vast minority) users have been in both groups, we are taking it into account in our analysis. The intent has also been discussed in the MSE post and the blog post linked from there. Thanks for your feedback. – Yaakov Ellis ♦️ [Nov 11 at 19:59](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390887/new-post-notices-closed-on-hold-etc-rolling-out-on-stack-overflow#comment739622_390887)".

It is still not completely clear ***if*** they switched people intentionally early on (as was explained in the deleted comment) and then later decided to stick with IP-based *registration* but there is a question asked Nov 5 at 9:53: "[Different post notices from different machines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391063/3648282)" (which remains unanswered, officially); and it seems clear from the comment that he tires of the question. That question also contains a comment, pointing to [shog9's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390974/good-to-see-improvements-happening-in-the-core-product#comment738785_390974), describing IP-based A/B as jarring and advised against.